Why can ffmpeg cause a reboot?
Four times in a row, when I started a short simple ffmpeg command on my Ubuntu host, after about ten seconds it rebooted cleanly.  Nothing appeared in /var/log/syslog.  The fourth time, I ran it inside strace, hoping for a clue:
strace -o strace.log /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex '[1:v]format=yuva444p,lut=c3=128,negate[video2withAlpha],[0:v][video2withAlpha]overlay[out]' -map [out] diff.mp4
The logfile strace.log ended abruptly:
...
futex(0x562a45c7f1f0, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, NULL, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY) = 0
futex(0x562a45c7f1a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x562a4c7918a0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
futex(0x562a4c7918a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x562a4c78e09c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 12
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
futex(0x562a45f63d4c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x562a45c73e88, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
write(2, "frame=   99 fps= 20 q=28.0 size="..., 99) = 99
futex(0x562a45f640cc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
...
futex(0x562a45c7f1f4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, NULL, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY) = 0
futex(0x562a45c7f1a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0

The console got farther than frame 99, so strace might not have been helpful:
frame=  415 fps= 20 q=28.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:14.83 bitrate=2969.0kbits/s speed=0.709x

How could ffmpeg run as a normal user provoke a reboot, repeatedly?
Where else might I find clues as to why, and how I might prevent that?
(Tweaking ffmpeg's options and inputs seems like a wild goose chase:  I'm not concerned about ffmpeg misbehaving, I'm concerned about how the crash could happen.)
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
ffmpeg 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1.
The input videos to ffmpeg are just a few seconds long, and play cleanly.

Clarifications, from comments:
The ffmpeg version is Ubuntu's current one.
The host is a fit-PC Tensor-I22, core i7, extra cooling, 64 GB, no graphics, headless.
sensors reports the usual temperatures, 30 deg C.  It's not working hard.
Ever since deployment, it runs other hours-long CPU-intensive and disk-intensive tasks fine, at higher temperatures.

Does the same happen when you start anything CPU-intensive, or, GPU-intensive?

CPU overheating, power supply browning out, faulty motherboard power regulators. Could be a lot of things.

Maybe a buggy ffmpeg version, have you tried a more updated version or an older version to see it the same happens?
